# ArrayList inside HashTable for Multiple Values

Tags: java, arraylist, hashtable

I'm trying to make a hashTable (multiValueMap) with a Key and an arrayList (alMissingValues) for values by project manager. My problem is the arrayList never starts over when there's a new project manager. I've tried clearing the arraylist after the values are added to the hashTable but it clears all the values in the hashTable too. Is this because the arrayList is only referenced in the hashTable value?

The function addMissingValues(strProjMgr, strDOORSName, missingValues) parameters are

- String strProjMgr
- String strDOORSName
- ArrayList missingValues

Code

```
function addMissingValues(strProjMgr, strDOORSName, missingValues){

    var docID = delta.getID();
    var strDOORSNameBoilerP= "<br /><b>Document ID</b> " + docID + ", </b><br /><i><b>DOORS Module</b> " + strDOORSName + "</i><br />";
    var strHeaderText = strDOORSNameBoilerP + missingValues+ "<br /><br />";
    
    var alMissingValues = new java.util.ArrayList();
    
    // Create an array list to hold all the missing values and doc boilerplate info
    // My problem is the alMissingValues arraylist is stacking missing items on top of eachother
    // This never groups by project manager
    // Is it only storing a reference to this arrayList. Because when I try to clear it it
    // deletes all items in it?
    
    alMissingValues.add(strHeaderText);
    // Add the project manager as a key, and multiple missingValues in arrayList
    multiValueMap.put(strProjMgr, alMissingValues);

}
```

Comment: Is this Java or JavaScript?

Comment: It's weird. It's Java inside JavaScript. It's how PTC does their trigger script coding

Comment: Including some context/background might help, since people browsing the Java tag might be confused. Is this related [PTC > Windchill > Using Event Triggers to Run Custom Java Code > Using Java Classes](https://support.ptc.com/help/windchillrvs/r12.3.1.0/en/index.html#page/IntegrityHelp%2Fserv_trig_running_java_in_triggers.mif-2.html%23)?

Answer (score 1):

To fix this issue, you can create a new ArrayList for each project manager. First, check if the project manager already exists in the multiValueMap. If they don't, create a new ArrayList, add the missing values, and put it into the multiValueMap. If they do exist, get the existing ArrayList, add the missing values, and update the value in the multiValueMap.

Here's the updated addMissingValues function:

```
function addMissingValues(strProjMgr, strDOORSName, missingValues) {
    var docID = delta.getID();
    var strDOORSNameBoilerP = "<br /><b>Document ID</b> " + docID + ", </b><br /><i><b>DOORS Module</b> " + strDOORSName + "</i><br />";
    var strHeaderText = strDOORSNameBoilerP + missingValues + "<br /><br />";

    var alMissingValues;

    // Check if the project manager already exists in the multiValueMap
    if (multiValueMap.containsKey(strProjMgr)) {
        // If the project manager exists, get the existing ArrayList
        alMissingValues = multiValueMap.get(strProjMgr);
    } else {
        // If the project manager doesn't exist, create a new ArrayList
        alMissingValues = new java.util.ArrayList();
    }

    // Add the missing values to the ArrayList
    alMissingValues.add(strHeaderText);

    // Update the multiValueMap with the new ArrayList for the project manager
    multiValueMap.put(strProjMgr, alMissingValues);
}
```